# Apocalyptic scifi movie with the Earth getting hotter and hotter

Tags: story-identification, movie

What’s the name of the movie about the Earth getting hotter and hotter? The main character gets trapped in a house with a family of cannibals. She is rescued, I remember, by a young guy she had mat in a tunnel.

No one can go outside so they have to stay covered or under something all the time.

I watched the movie on DVD about 15 years ago but it may not have been new at the time.

Comment: "What’s the name of the movie about the Earth getting hotter and hotter?" You may be thinking of real life over the past 150 years or so.

Answer (score 7):

Is it a German film? If so, it sounds like [Hell](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt1643222/) (no pun intended, that's the name of this 2011 movie)

> In the not too distant future, people struggle to survive their greatest enemy, the sun.

From the [Wikipedia plot summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hell_(2011_film)):

> Marie sleeps in Elisabeth's barn, only to awake to find herself locked in. Peering out the slats of the barn, she sees what looks like abducted captives being led about. Elisabeth opens the locked door and tells Marie that Phillip will be used like livestock, in the absence of other food and that Marie and Leonie will be forced to marry the sons of the farmers. When Elisabeth's son Micha opens the door, Marie engages in kissing with him, but then strikes him with a large piece of wood. Injured, Micha tries to choke her, but then Leonie smashes a heavy object on him, knocking him out. Leonie escapes from the barn and hides in the woods, but Marie is bound and put in the slaughterhouse after refusing to eat human flesh during dinner. Marie witnesses Phillip's execution, but manages to cut her ziplock cuffs and escape. She opens a locked door in the barn, where she finds many captives, including Tom. The captives flee from the farm, with the family in pursuit. Tom fights with and dispatches several of the farmers. Marie manages to escape and runs through the woods in search of Leonie. When she finds her, Leonie is being bound by one of Elisabeth's adult sons. Elisabeth confronts Marie, who kills her with a captive bolt pistol she stole from the slaughterhouse. While the adult son mourns Elisabeth, Marie releases Leonie. The two sisters and Tom flee to the mountains, where they find water. Up in the sky, they see birds. Looking over the ridge at a chain of hills in hope of a better fate there, they can see nothing but even more blighted wasteland down in the valley.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to explain why you think this might be the correct film, specifying any plot points that match the description given in the question, and any that don't. For example, was the main character a woman? Did she get trapped in a house with a family of cannibals? And was she rescued by a guy she met in a tunnel?